# Display plugin block markup raw

Tags: 8, blocks

I have built a custom block plugin in Drupal 8. However, I needed to insert some svg elements in the markup, which get all filtered out. Is there a way for me to specify to display the raw output, so that the svg does not get filtered out?

```
  public function build() {

    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div><svg>.....</svg></div>',
    );
 }
?>
```

I have tried adding `'#template' => '{{ value|raw }}'` and played some with it - but could not get it to work. There must be some way to allow me to insert svg in there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an inline template:

```
  public function build() {

  return array(
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => '<div><svg>{{ var }}</svg></div>',
    '#context' => array(
      'var' => $svg,
    ),
  );
```

You can use the inline template with an empty context, if you have no vars that need to be escaped:

```
  return array(
        '#type' => 'inline_template',
        '#template' => '<div><svg>...</svg></div>',
        '#context' => array(),
      );
```